# Ember transitionTo only if current route is different

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I initially start at the root level (/) and I have multiple links (say Link1, Link2, Link3)

Now each of these links displays a common grid i.e. I use same route/controller/template JS, but re-render the grid, by setting some attributes dynamically on the controller

Thus in my application.js, I do

```
this.controllerFor('my-grid').set('attr1', params[0].value);
this.controllerFor('my-grid').set('attr2', params[1].value);
this.transitionTo('my-grid');
```

Is this the correct way to transition ?

I mean, specifically I need

```
this.transitionTo('my-grid');
```

to be called only once (say on click of link1 from root), since after then, clicks on link2, link3 would just need a change of attribute values on my same controller and should just re-render the grid (after server api call)

Please suggest if there is some condition that I can check for calling
this.transitionTo('my-grid');

Answer (score 0):

In your application you can check `ApplicationController.currentPath`:

```
this.controllerFor('my-grid').setProperties({
    attr1: params[0].value,
    attr2: params[1].value
});

if (this.controllerFor('application').get('currentPath') !== 'my-grid') {
    this.transitionTo('my-grid');
}
```

Comment: so this can be done inside my "my-grid" controller and not inside the application.js route ?

Comment: It should be done in `application.js` route, but it might work in `my-grid` **route**.